# Pass counter parameter to postgres sql script

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, scripting

I have script myScript.sql. I am running it with some number ./myScript.sql 1000. It executes below

```
psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p ${DB_PORT} -U ${DB_USER} ${DB_INSTANCE} -f myScript.sql -v myNumber="'$1'"> /dev/null
```

And sql itself

```
DO
$do$
    DECLARE
        _counter int := 0;
    BEGIN
        WHILE _counter < :myNumber
            LOOP
                _counter := _counter + 1;
                insert into mySchema.myTable (id,action_id)
                values (x, y);
            END LOOP;
    END
$do$
```

But it fails... What is wrong, I tried already various option, nothing is working.

Comment: Can you say what fails?  Do you get an error?

Comment: It don't recognize what is the :myNumber

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 6:   WHILE _counter IN 1..:myNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSQL variables are only taken into account in SQL statements and not in PL/pgSQL statements.

You can try:

```
drop table v_myNumber;
select :myNumber into v_myNumber;
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  _counter int = 0;
  BEGIN
    WHILE _counter <  (select * from v_myNumber) 
    LOOP
      _counter = _counter + 1;
     RAISE NOTICE '_counter=%', _counter;
    END LOOP;
  END;
$do$
```

Execution says:

```
$ psql -e -f tloop.sql  -v myNumber=3
drop table v_myNumber;
DROP TABLE
select 3 into v_myNumber;
SELECT 1
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  _counter int = 0;
  BEGIN
    WHILE _counter <  (select * from v_myNumber) 
    LOOP
      _counter = _counter + 1;
     RAISE NOTICE '_counter=%', _counter;
    END LOOP;
  END;
$do$
psql:tloop.sql:14: NOTICE:  _counter=1
psql:tloop.sql:14: NOTICE:  _counter=2
psql:tloop.sql:14: NOTICE:  _counter=3
DO
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand what is "drop table" and "select from that table"

Why table???

Comment: Running`select 3 into t` creates a table named `t` with a single row and a single column containing the value 3. You need to choose carefully the name of this table because if this table already exists this SELECT statement fails.